Unable to see register button on Woocommerce_my_account Login page
I Cant see the "register now" button on Login Woocommerce_my_account Login page. I have enabled "Allow account creation on myAccount" but I dont need registration form I need a button so I can redirect it to my custom registration page.
I have enabled "Allow account creation on myAccount" And Also "Anyone can register" option still I am getting the not the option to redirect other page help please

You need to override via your child theme the WooCommerce template file myaccount/form-login.php… See Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme.
